# string.includes() has a word on a ban list

Tags: javascript, string

Is there any way to use the string.includes() in conjunction with some sort of ban list? Can I have a list of words banned and check if they're in a string? Here's an example of what I want to acheive:

```
var ban = [word1, word2, word3];
var str = prompt("What's your name?");
if(str.includes(ban)) {
alert("that is banned");
}
```

Comment: sure but it is not very reliable to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: that it's very easy to circumvent by replacing any of the characters or spelling mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to check each word in the ban list individually.

The following block of code would make sure every banned word does appear in the given str.

```
if (!ban.every(bannedWord => !str.includes(bannedWord)) {
   alert("that is banned");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use es6, the `.some` array method might be helpful. It just checks the given condition for each item of an array, eg:

```js
var ban = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];
var str1 = "Hey its a test with a banned word! word3!";
var str2 = "No banned words here!";

function checkBanned(str) {
  if (ban.some(x => str.includes(x))) {
    console.log(str, "is banned");
  } else {
    console.log(str, "is not banned");
  }
}

checkBanned(str1);
checkBanned(str2);
```

As mentioned, however, this is only going to blacklist very specific strings that exactly match something in your list. Differences in capitalization or slight spelling variations will allow a word to escape this check. Furthermore, even strings that include a banned word as part of another word will be captured, which is something you may not desire. Eg,  "shitake mushroom" might be accidentally banned.

Comment: I understand the whole slight change thing. I was just seeing if it was even possible to do that. Thanks for your help!